# Spring's Json not being resolved with appropriate response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I've tried to have a controller in Spring return a JSON response to no avail using the Jackson classes as [recommended with 3.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/). I've got the jackson jar files(jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar & jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.5.jar) in my class path of course.

As for the appconfig.xml entries, I'm not sure I need these. I've put them in there as a last act of desperation before returning to ol' fashion non-json ajax.

In debug, I watch the controller get the request, return the foo and then, in firebug, get a 406.

The error messages are as follows: 
From the logger when set to debug:
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

From the response:
(406) The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().

My appconfig.xml is here:

```xml
    <!-- Configures support for @Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
    </bean>
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="foo/bar", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody foo getFoo(@RequestParam String fooId) {
    return new foo(fooId); 
}
```

On the jsp, where the ajax call is made:

```
function addRow() {
  $.getJSON("foo/bar", {
    fooId: 1
  }, function(data) {
    alert("it worked.");
  });
}
```

Let me know if there's any more info that is needed.

Comment: more coverage at [Spring JSON request getting 406 (not Acceptable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get rid of all Jackson beans, and of the json mapping in the negotiating resolver. the `mvc:annotation-driven` should configure everything you need for the Jackson serialization to work.

Comment: I tried this too, but it didn't work for me. Any ideas? I have Jackson on my classpath, and I'm using a plain old object but it still doesn't seem to cut it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure the POJO you return has get()ers, one for each field.
2. Make sure the appserver (Tomcat) has the libraries even if you are sure your build system (Eclipse/Maven) does.

I've had this error twice now.
Just now I added getters to my pojo.  The 406 error went away and I got JSON as expected.
I assume that because my fields were package-protected (the default access), it would grab them, but I guess not.
For the record, in case it matters, I also made the POJO implement Serializable, toString(), serialVersionUID, no-arg constructor, and explicit constructors.

The prior time I cleaned/cleared/refreshed my Tomcat cache and did whatever else to force it to reload.  I believe when I added the Jackson dependencies, it fixed my compile time errors, but since tomcat missed them, at runtime Spring MVC did not discover the Jackson libraries, and produced the 406 error about unacceptable response type.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure that you add two jackson related jar files.

- `jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar`
- `jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.8.jar`

The version can be different.

Comment: Yeah, this was the thing I was missing. For using `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` , the default will json format and the jackson jars will be considered for conversion of your pojo.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old thread, but maybe someone will encounter the same problem as me. I got that exception when migrating an application from Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE to Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE. In my case updating Jackson from 1.9.x to 2.4.x did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I have got same exception when migrating from spring 3.x to spring 4.x.

I solved it with updating jackson dependencies from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Nothing else was needed for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the Accept: application/xml header does not work. But sending Accept: application/json  actually works, and jackson mapper kicks in. I got rid of my 406 and got my serialized java object in json format with no more config than @ResponseBody and return new MyObject()
:)
Thanks skaffman for this information, and thanks Bozho for the working header value :D

Comment: What about using `produces="application/json"` on the @RequestBody annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This question pops up everywhere on the net and I got bitten by it a couple of times. Spring 3.0.6 (and 5 possibly) has some issues in rendering json. Once I changed to 3.1.0.RELEASE version eveyrything worked AS IS. Without any config changes. Things to note is, the return method must have @ResponseBody (as in the example before) and  must be in servlet-context.xml or your spring context configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer is a bit late, but it may help some one else visiting this question.

I got my problem resolved by adding

```
 hibernate-validator-4.0.2
```

and gave me another exception (class not found exception: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory) which i resolved by adding

```
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
```

I hope it will help someone.