# Ignore Accept header in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that serves files (images, pdfs, etc,.):

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/{filename}")
    public Object download(@PathVariable String filename) throws Exception {
        returns MyFile.findFile(filename);
    }

}
```

If I request a file with the following Accept header I get a 406:

> ```
> Request     
> URL: http://localhost:8080/files/thmb_AA039258_204255d0.png
> Request Method:GET
> Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
> Request Headers
> Accept:*/*
> ```

If I request the same file with the following Accept header I get a 200:

> ```
> URL: http://localhost:8080/files/thmb_AA039258_204255d0.png
> Request Method: GET 
> Status Code:200 OK
> Request Headers
> Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
> ```

This is the only view resolver in my spring-mvc context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
   <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

Is there anyway to configure spring mvc to ignore the Accept header? I've seen example of doing this with ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, but only for handling xml and json.

Comment: This is a very similar question but for json: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315288/spring-returning-json-with-responsebody-when-the-accept-header-is-throws-htt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this is the code I ended up with to get it working:

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/{filename}")
    public void download(@PathVariable String filename, ServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        MyFile file = MyFile.find(filename);
        response.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        response.getOutputStream().write(file.getBytes());

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this to lock to the JSON response type:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
        configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true);
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    }

}
```

`favorPathExtension(false)` is needed because Spring by default (at least in 4.1.5) favors path-based content negotiation (i.e. if the URL ends with ".xml", it will try to return XML, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

When you use ResponseBody annotation, I think that is part of the deal that it looks at the Accept header and tries to do some mapping or whatever. There are plenty of other ways to send a response though if you can't figure out how to do it with that annotation.