# JSON response from Spring Controller not getting resolved

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc

I have a similar issue as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340050/springs-json-not-being-resolved-with-appropriate-response?tab=oldest#tab-top) . But i cannot solve it with the solutions provided there.

My spring application xml has only mvc annotation driven element.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

The controller code is as given.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Book performSearch(@RequestParam("CHARS") String title) {
return (Book) library.getBook(title);
}
```

In my javascript I have an jQuery request which tries to get JSON from the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function doSearch() {   
    $.getJSON("addBook/search.htm", { CHARS: $('#searchBox').val() }, function(data) 
    {   
        alert("Got Response");
        $('#results').text('');
            for (var index in data) {
                $('#results').append('<p>' + data[index].title + '</p>'); 
            }
    });
 }
 </script>
```

I have a textbox which calls this JS

```
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" onKeyUp="doSearch();" />

<div id="results">Results</div>
```

While keying in the controller code is called, but the response that comes back has a status code 406 and says Not Acceptable

What could be the problem here? Also can I set the values of "Accept" header to application/json in the jQuery call? If so how?

I am using a locale resolver to resolve the locale. Could this be a problem?

Thanks 
Dhanush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and jackson-mapper jars on your classpath.

Comment: I have jackson core in my POM. Isn't that enough? Or do i need to add all of them `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.4</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: @dhanush check your `WEB-INF/lib`. Is it there ?

Comment: Oh definitely it is there . What I meant was I have only jackson-core-lgpl-1.7.4.jar in the lib got downloaded through the POM.xml file (as dependency) for my maven project. Isn't that enough?

Comment: researched some more and figured out that u need to add jackson mapper also to classpath . The pom dependecy `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.4</version>
 </dependency>` was added and the application was redeployed. Now works like charm. Thanks