# Exception with Spring ExceptionHandler and Rest response

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

I'm using @ExceptionHandler to manage all my exception and to return a JSON response for any REST API that throws exception.
At the moment I manage two exception, the first is ResourceNotFoundException and it works but the second, FileExtensionException, it doesn't work.
It throws this exception in eclipse console and nothing into rest response.

> 2015-09-21 09:09:05.197 ERROR 7500 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to invoke
>   @ExceptionHandler method: public matlab.ErrorResponse
>   matlab.ErrorController.errorHandler(java.lang.Exception)
>
> org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2015-09-21 09:09:05.201 ERROR 7500 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page
>   from request [/ManagmentFile/zipDownload] due to exception [The
>   selected file has a different extension:xlsx and not zip]
>
> matlab.FileExtensionException: The selected file has a different
>   extension:xlsx and not zip    at
>   matlab.FileServices.getZipFile(FileServices.java:46)  at
>   matlab.ws.FileManagerImpl.getZip(FileManagerImpl.java:38)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

These are the codes called by webservices:

```
public FileSystemResource getZipFile(String fileName) throws FileExtensionException {
    String ext=FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
    if (ext!= "zip")
        throw new FileExtensionException(ext + " and not zip");
    return new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName));
}
```

the exception:

```
package matlab;

public class FileExtensionException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileExtensionException(String message){
        super("The selected file has a different extension:" + message);
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Response<Collection<FileModel>> getAllFiles(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Collection<FileModel> result;
    result = file.getAllFiles(path);
    return new Response<Collection<FileModel>>(HttpStatus.OK.value(),result);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/zipDownload", produces="application/zip", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getZip(@RequestParam(value="filePath", required=true) String filePath ) throws FileExtensionException{
    return file.getZipFile(filePath);
}
```

ResourceNotFoundException

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String path){
        super("The specified path: "+ path +"  doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

the ErrorControl

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class ErrorController {

    /**
     * 
     * @param e: exception thrown
     * @return ErroreResponse
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse errorHandler(Exception e){   
        //Make the exception by buildErrorResponse
        return ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
    }

}
```

the error build:

```
public class ErrorResponseBuilder {

    public ErrorResponseBuilder() { 
    }

    /**
     * Build exception response beginning from exception
     * @param e exception thrown
     * @return ErrorResponse: response of an exception
     */
    public static ErrorResponse buildErrorResponse(Exception e){
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatusManager.getHttpCode(e),e.getClass().getName(),e.getMessage(),errors.toString());
    }

}
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your spring configuration with:

```
<bean id="methodHandlerExceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
                <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I have changed but the problem is here. Futhermore both FileExtensionException  and ResourceNotFoundException used the RuntimeException.
The exceptions are handled and the Responde build but FileExtensionException throws exception

Comment: OK, i see the problem is `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation`

Please check this posts:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340050/springs-json-not-being-resolved-with-appropriate-response

Comment: I have used last link and the exception now is into response but the exception is org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException and not  the mine FileExtensionException. The problem is the launch of this spring exception oafter the mine

Comment: Sure, above I have posted my code. I have find the problem, it is the RestController because it should return zip but with exception it doesn't map the exception (I have tried to change the returned type and it works)